# Why is requesting for authorization of my Twitter app for a new user generating a PIN?

Tags: twitter, oauth

I've created a twitter app and I have all the credentials (access token, secret, consumer key and secret). I'm using [Abraham's Twitter Oauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/releases). I've been able to get the application running but I am currently unable to Authorize a new account successfully. Instead, it is requesting for a new user to input a PIN generated after the user has granted access, before the authorization is complete. 
[image: See Image]

I've done some lookup on the internet and it pointed out to Twitter.com's manual [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/pin-based) and [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing). From what I've been able to read up, [Implementing a desktop sign in request](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing) requires `oauth_callback` value. I've tried to add a value to this parameter, but it returns an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <hash> <error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error> <request>/oauth/request_token</request> </hash> '`, but if I don't add a value to the `oauth_callback` parameter, it redirects to Twitter.com's authorization page successfully, but then, generates a PIN which will be required to be filled in the application.
I sincerely do not know how to go round this, any help will be much appreciated. 
Here's my code below:

```
require_once "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
//Check if form was submitted
if(isset($_GET['activate-account']) && $_GET['activate-account'] == 'true'){
session_start();

//Get App Details (Consumer key and secret) from DB
$appID = 1;
$consumerKey = getAutoTweetPart($appID, 'consumer_key');
$consumerSecret = getAutoTweetPart($appID, 'consumer_secret');

$callBack = '';

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

$request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => $callBack));

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

$url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $request_token['oauth_token']));
header('Location: '. $url);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check that your app (linked from https://apps.twitter.com) has a callback URL specified, so that you are not using desktop mode.  The callback URL should not be locked unless it is always the same e.g. constant host/port.

Then your request_token call can specify the URL you want the user redirected to.

This is part of the flow described here https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does the `XXX` in the link you provided stand for? Moreso, I did not specify the callback URL when  was creating the app, because I also have a function to auto-publish to all the authorized twitter handles.

Comment: I think I have seen what you mean. I checked the app details screen, and saw these values:
`Callback URL:  None`
`Callback URL Locked: No`
`Sign in with Twitter: Yes`.
Is there something I am missing @YuriSchimke?

Comment: Put a dummy callback URL in but *don't* lock it.

Comment: For other people's benefit, the XXX is your app id, since the number differs as apps are private.

Comment: Thanks @Yuri. That did it. 
But I can't find the app in the [List of Applications](https://twitter.com/settings/applications) that can access the account.

Comment: authorise is not the final call, you probably want to call <https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/access_token>

This gives you your final token and secret to use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100611/discussion-between-samuel-asor-and-yuri-schimke).